# GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext) vs launch() in a class extends CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As codes shown below,

1. Will two `launchWithXXX` functions run in `MainScope`? Are they creating the same coroutine environment for running both jobs?
2. Will both functions be canceled when `dispose()` is called?

```
class A : CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

    fun launchWithGlobalScope() {
        GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext) {
            // Run jobs
        }
    }

    fun launchWithClassScope() {
        launch {
            // Run jobs too
        }
    }

    fun dispose() {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for 1: No. [`MainScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope.html) defines a scope for doing something with UI components. So it runs in the UI thread of your platform. [`GlobalScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) is a scope with an own thread pool and runs the coroutine with one of those threads.

Answer for 2: `cancel` does only stop the `MainScope` in your example and all coroutines created with this scope.

Comment: Thanks! I find `GlobalScope.launch(coroutineContext)` in Android `Anko` framework when creating listeners for views, these methods only accept a `CoroutineContext` parameter while not `CoroutineScope` [see here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/b036b59aa5d9d24dc49ad2dfcc57fe4114436175/anko/library/generated/sdk28-coroutines/src/main/java/ListenersWithCoroutines.kt#L312). Is that means I can't cancel the job inside listener when I call `cancel()` of a `Activity() : CoroutineScope by MainScope()`? Are there any potential dangers when I use these `Anko` methods?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer and therefore I'm not using Anko. That said, the code from Anko looks like they did not incorporate the structured concurrency changes. One year ago coroutines added structured concurrency and from then it was not allowed to `launch` a coroutine without a scope. A (discouraged) fallback was to use `GlobalScope`. But with this it is not possible to cancel these coroutines. To answer your question, if you use these methods the registered handlers may be invoked after the view was disposed, which may be dangerous.

Comment: `GlobalScope` has empty coroutine context so when you pass in the `coroutineContext` of `MainScope()` to that `launch`, then there is no difference. The first `launch` is just a more confusing variant of the second.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/762440a94264948f1f2c47e5d04713bfb35ce3e3/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Builders.common.kt#L26